# How does Firestarter work?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

The tooltip for Akarat's Champion - Firestarter states:

> Dealing damage burns enemies with the power of Akarat, dealing 460% weapon damage as fire over 3 seconds.

What sources of damage trigger this effect?  In particular, I'm asking about the passive equipment procs such as the Fire Chains from Maximus, Fire Walkers, and Pox Faulds.  Do those count?  What about damage from summoned units (Bowmen from Phalanx) and followers?

Is there a cooldown or do faster ticks/attacks proc the burn more times?  Does it stack?

Comment: +300 ? oh my god! :o

Comment: @Fabián well I'm hoping for a good answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo3Crusaders/comments/25p2e5/lets_talk_about_fire_starter_rune/chjcyk0) and this [post](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10494793998) the dot procs with 100% chance (no proc coefficients) and it stacks (which can lead to ticks with over one million damage). This also means faster/more attacks will proc the dot more often, as there seems to be no coooldown.

According to this [post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo3Crusaders/comments/25ulgp/what_is_the_best_skillbuild_for_procing_akarats/chkw413) it procs from Firewalkers ground effect damage, but not from Maximus fire chains or Phalanx Bowmen (this [post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo3Crusaders/comments/25p2e5/lets_talk_about_fire_starter_rune/chjzpl7)).

As the posts also mention, this is extremly powerful and may get reduced / nerfed in a future patch (for example by applying proc coefficients).

PS: This all comes from players, there are no official sources which explain the skills in that much detail. It is consistent with my own (limited) experience playing crusader.

PS2: I did some own testing and could confirm, that Phalanx Bowmen attacks did not proc the Firestarter effect, but the ground effect damage from Firewalkers did (I do not have a Maximus to test that one).

Comment: unfortunately your [link](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo3Crusaders/comments/25p2e5/lets_talk_about_fire_starter_rune/chji1ql) actually contradicts your first one about firewalkers in that it says maximus doesn't proc fire starter.

Comment: Edited, I only read the first post from that thread.

Comment: good initial research but can you add on top of it by doing some in game testing since you mentioned you have a crusader? Also, you haven't addressed whether or not summoned units and pets proc firestarter.

Comment: I addressed summoned units/pets in my edited second paragraph. I will do some testing, but that may have to wait for the weekend.

Comment: That's no problem, I'm willing to wait for a well researched answer

Comment: @z' Added results from my own testing.